# EJBException when creating entity bean

Tags: java, ejb

I added and modified some fields in the entity bean (and did some other changes also) and after that I get an EJBException while creating the entity bean. Before doing the changes everything worked. The TipListBean is the entity bean I call create from. Here are the exceptions:

```
[#|2013-11-15T14:41:36.063+0000|INFO|sun-appserver-pe8.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb|_ThreadID=17;|EJB5018: An exception was thrown during an ejb invocation on [TipListBean]|#]

[#|2013-11-15T14:41:36.063+0000|INFO|sun-appserver-pe8.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb|_ThreadID=17;|
javax.ejb.EJBException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.processSystemException(BaseContainer.java:2807)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionNoTx(BaseContainer.java:2647)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionBeanMgTx(BaseContainer.java:2585)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:2485)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:819)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:160)
    at $Proxy20.addTip(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:167)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at beans._TipList_DynamicStub.addTip(_TipList_DynamicStub.java)
    at web.MakeTip.doPost(MakeTip.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:767)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:161)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:604)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ReadTask.executeProcessorTask(ReadTask.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ReadTask.doTask(ReadTask.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:281)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:83)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: Transaction aborted; nested exception is: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.; nested exception is: 
    javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at beans.TipListBean.addTip(TipListBean.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil$2.run(SecurityUtil.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.doAsPrivileged(EJBSecurityManager.java:957)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:158)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:151)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException: Transaction aborted; nested exception is: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.; nested exception is: 
    javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:657)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:279)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at beans._TipHome_DynamicStub.create(_TipHome_DynamicStub.java)
    at beans.TipListBean.addTip(TipListBean.java:21)
    ... 50 more
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException: Transaction aborted; nested exception is: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.; nested exception is: 
    javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
    at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransaction.commit(J2EETransaction.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.distributedtx.J2EETransactionManagerOpt.commit(J2EETransactionManagerOpt.java:336)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.completeNewTx(BaseContainer.java:2732)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:2521)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:819)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBHomeInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBHomeInvocationHandler.java:231)
    at $Proxy17.create(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:167)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at beans._TipHome_DynamicStub.create(_TipHome_DynamicStub.java)
    at beans.TipListBean.addTip(TipListBean.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil$2.run(SecurityUtil.java:153)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.doAsPrivileged(EJBSecurityManager.java:957)
    at com.sun.enterprise.security.SecurityUtil.invoke(SecurityUtil.java:158)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBObjectInvocationHandler.java:151)
    at $Proxy20.addTip(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:167)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at beans._TipList_DynamicStub.addTip(_TipList_DynamicStub.java)
    at web.MakeTip.doPost(MakeTip.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:767)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:161)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:604)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ReadTask.executeProcessorTask(ReadTask.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ReadTask.doTask(ReadTask.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:281)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:83)
|#]

[#|2013-11-15T14:41:36.065+0000|WARNING|sun-appserver-pe8.2|javax.enterprise.system.stream.err|_ThreadID=17;|
java.rmi.ServerException: RemoteException occurred in server thread; nested exception is: 
    java.rmi.RemoteException
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:657)
    at javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.wrapException(Util.java:279)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:177)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.bcel.BCELStubBase.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at beans._TipList_DynamicStub.addTip(_TipList_DynamicStub.java)
    at web.MakeTip.doPost(MakeTip.java:29)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:767)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:860)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor66.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:585)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:249)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:517)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:282)
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:165)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:257)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:161)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:263)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invokeInternal(StandardContextValve.java:225)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.invoke(ContainerBase.java:933)
    at org.apache.coyote.tomcat5.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:189)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:604)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:475)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ReadTask.executeProcessorTask(ReadTask.java:371)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.ReadTask.doTask(ReadTask.java:264)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.TaskBase.run(TaskBase.java:281)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.connector.grizzly.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:83)
Caused by: java.rmi.RemoteException
|#]
```

The caller TipListBean class and the TipBean class that Im trying to call create on.

```
package beans;

import javax.ejb.FinderException;
import javax.ejb.SessionBean;
import javax.ejb.SessionContext; 
import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.rmi.PortableRemoteObject;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;

public class TipListBean implements SessionBean{

 public String addTip(String result, String amount, String tipster, String targetId, String sport, 
   String league, String homePlayer, String visitorPlayer, String closingtime)
  throws CreateException, CreateException, FinderException, RemoteException {

  Tip tip = null;
  try{
   TipHome tipHome = getTipHome();
   tip = tipHome.create(targetId, result, amount, tipster, targetId);
   return "Tip and Target created with the following ID: "; //+ tip.getTickerSymbol();
  } 
  catch (CreateException ce){
   throw ce;
  } 
  catch(Exception ex){ 
   throw new RuntimeException(ex);
  }
 }

 private TipHome getTipHome() throws NamingException {
  InitialContext jndiContext = new InitialContext();
  TipHome home = (TipHome)jndiContext.lookup("ejb/beans.Tip"); 
  return home;   
 }

 public void ejbActivate() {}
 public void ejbPassivate() {}
 public void ejbRemove() {}
 public void ejbCreate() {}
 public void setSessionContext(SessionContext context) {}
}



package beans;

import javax.ejb.EntityBean;
import javax.ejb.EntityContext;
import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import java.rmi.RemoteException;
import javax.ejb.FinderException;

public abstract class TipBean implements EntityBean{

 private EntityContext _context;
 public abstract String getTickerSymbol() throws RemoteException;
 public abstract void setTickerSymbol(String ticker) throws RemoteException;
 public abstract String getResult() throws RemoteException;
 public abstract void setResult(String result) throws RemoteException;
 public abstract String getAmount() throws RemoteException;
 public abstract void setAmount(String amount) throws RemoteException;
 public abstract String getTipster() throws RemoteException;
 public abstract void setTipster(String tipster) throws RemoteException;
 public abstract String getTargetId() throws RemoteException;
 public abstract void setTargetId(String targetId) throws RemoteException;

 public String ejbCreate(String ticker, String result, String amount, String tipster, String targetId) 
  throws CreateException, RemoteException {
  setTickerSymbol(ticker);
  setResult(result);
  setAmount(amount);
  setTipster(tipster);
  setTargetId(targetId);
  return null;
 }

 public void ejbPostCreate(String ticker, String result, String amount, String tipster, String targetId) 
  throws CreateException{
 }

 public void setEntityContext(EntityContext ctx){
  _context = ctx;
 }

 public void unsetEntityContext(){
  _context = null;
 }

 public void ejbRemove(){}
 public void ejbLoad(){}
 public void ejbStore(){}
 public void ejbPassivate(){}
 public void ejbActivate(){}

}
```

Comment: Please provide any code. Neither my crystal ball nor me knows which code you're talking about ;-)

Comment: :) Code is now provided.

Comment: Please throw RuntimeExcpetion with root cause included: `throw new RuntimeException(ex);` And repost the stacktrace. That'd be more easier to identify the cause.

Comment: The stacktrace says `at beans.TipListBean.addTip(TipListBean.java:30)`. Is that the call to `TipHome tipHome = getTipHome();`? If so, maybe your TipHome object isn't registered successfully at the naming service?!

Comment: stack trace reposted.

Comment: When I comment out create the exception is no longer there so getTipHome()-call shouldn't be the reason for the exception(?)

Comment: Show us the code, which registers the `TipHome` object at the naming service.

Comment: I think `getTipHome()` IS the reason, because `lookup()` returns `null`. Check that and tell us.

Comment: I don't explicitly register the object. I use the deployment tool for setting the jndi-name, and it seemed to work before and it works for the stateless session bean TipListBean. And it worked before with the same code except for the changes to the fields in the TipBean. Something in the deployment tool/related files might be different though. I was wondering could it be that the database operation fails because of the table fields has changed..

Comment: Well, as you use Remote EJB, could it happen that you forgot to provide the client (web) with an updated version of business interface?

Comment: I checked that the web archive contains the latest classes. Also I checked the ejb xml file and it contains the latest interface.

Comment: And I checked that tipHome is not null.

Comment: Anyone with some new ideas what could go wrong?